# How can I stop a moving sprite when a message box appears in vb?

Tags: vb.net

I have a sprite moving in a game and when it touches a door, it's location changes and a message box immediately appears at the same time. I have timers that cause the sprite to move when you press w, a, s, or d. I used 'Timer.Stop' to stop the sprite moving, but when the message appears, the sprite keeps walking in the direction you were just moving. Can someone help?

Comment: Crystal ball says that you must put the Stop() call *before* the MessageBox.Show() call.

Comment: That did the  trick, thank you!